# Session lifetime in magento2 frontend?

Tags: magento2, customer-session

What is the maximum session life time for the frontend customers in magento2?

Also, Is the session lifetime depends on session.gc_maxlifetime php variable?

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini file:
change session.gc_maxlifetime 86400

```
In your Magento admin Also check:

1.Store -> Configuration Sales-> Checkout -> Shopping Cart
Quote Lifetime (days)


2.Store -> Configuration ->General-> Web -> Default Cookie Settings
Cookie Lifetime
```

The lifetime of a customer shopping session is determined by several factors, including the length of the server session please check magento Document https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/customers/customer-online-options.html